# Director::protocolAndHost() lacks sufficient information - HTTP_HOST not set

Tags: php, apache, silverstripe

I'm getting the following error:

`PHP Warning:  Director::protocolAndHost() lacks sufficient information - HTTP_HOST not set. in /<path/to/project>/framework/control/Director.php on line 488`

But, when I add `print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);` to **mysite/_config.php** I get the appropriate url.

Any ideas what this could be? It started suddenly yesterday after weeks of developing on the same host. It's only happening on my remote environment. Local works fine. I haven't made any config changes.

I've looked at [this post on SS forums](https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/16369?start=0), as well [this tiny post](http://www.silverstrip.es/blog/file-to-url-mapping-and-symlinks/) since I am using a continuous deployment system, but neither have helped me so far.

Any ideas what this could be or where I should be looking? Many thanks.

My project uses:

- SilverStripe 3.6.0
- PHP 5.5.9
- Apache 2.4.7

Comment: This usually happens when running CLI. Is that what you're doing? If so, be sure to set $_FILE_TO_URL_MAPPING in your _ss_environment.php.

Comment: @UncleCheese I'm not running CLI. Actually, turns out this error has been happening for weeks now and is non-breaking for my project. Only noticed it now when looking into another issue. I'm going to see if I can clear it tomorrow by adding $_FILE_TO_URL_MAPPING as you've suggested.

Comment: for the cli issue i had:
`/**
 * This is used by sake to know which directory points to which URL
 */
global $_FILE_TO_URL_MAPPING;
$_FILE_TO_URL_MAPPING[__DIR__] = 'http://localhost:32773/';`
like written here: https://gist.github.com/ryanwachtl/5793212

Answer (score 2):

I got that same problem. To fix that, I have added below piece of code in _ss_environment.php or mysite/_config.php file.

```
global $_FILE_TO_URL_MAPPING;
$_FILE_TO_URL_MAPPING[__DIR__] = 'http://example.com';
```